# Android Studio logcat not showing the streams of messages when connected to physical device via adb

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I am working on an application which has been working well until recently the logcat stopped showing the streams of messages.
This means when debugging the app I can't locate the problem if the app crashes, or even the server response is not available.
All of my other apps are working fine.
This means it's a problem with this specific app

[image: This is the screen shot of my logcat]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You filtered by "Firebase". (See top right of panel)

Not all messages come from Firebase logs

Comment: Thanks really. This helped me